# Definition of a simply connected region

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Bak and Newman's *Complex Analysis,* and I am having a difficult time understanding the definition of a simply connected region. Here's the definition:

> A region $D$ is simply connected if its complement is “connected within $\epsilon$ to $\infty$.” That is, if for any $z_0 \in D^{c}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a continuous curve $\gamma (t), 0 \leq t < \infty$, such that:
>
> i) $d(\gamma(t), D^c) < \epsilon$ for all $t \geq 0$,
>
> ii) $\gamma(0) = z_0$,
>
> iii) $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } \gamma(t) = \infty$.

While I understand that, intuitively, the last two conditions state that $D^c$ is unbounded in the sense that any point in the complement can be "joined to $\infty$" using a line/curve that lies within $D^c$. What about the first condition? Also, it'd be great if someone could motivate this definition as well, without invoking algebraic toploogical notions.

Comment: What they are saying in effect is that the complement of $D$ in the **Riemann sphere** ($\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$) is connected.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You mean path connected, right? Well, that would imply connectedness in any case. I still don't get the first condition, though.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Does (i) imply that, since each point on the curve is arbitrarily close to points in $D^c$, the curve is contained in $D^c$.

Answer (score 1):

It would be instructive to consider the case of a region $D$ with a $2$-dimensional "hole" in it.  Taking a point $z_0$ in this hole, we would not be able to construct a curve which "goes to $\infty $" and which stays within $\epsilon $ of $D^c$.  Try drawing a picture...  This, intuitively,  is because $\gamma (t)$ would have to pass through $D$ to get to $\infty$, thereby creating some separation between $\gamma (t)$ and $D^c$, for certain $t$..

Comment: So (genuine question), does this mean that, say, $$(\mathbb{C} \setminus [0, \infty)) \cup \lbrace 1 \rbrace$$ is simply connected? Because this seems to fit the above definition, even though the unit circle exists in the set, but can't be "continuously deformed" to a point.

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't think your example would fit the definition of a "region" in $\mathbb C$...

Comment: Oh, do regions have to be open?

Comment: @TheoBendit or, the closure of an open set, i think...

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes, I did go through the example of why an annulus is not simply connected. Thanks for your answer.